# Removing an attribute from a parent element but not a child element

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the `href` attribute from the second `li` but not the child `li`'s, how can that be done?

At the moment it's removing the attribute from the second `li` and the `li` with "Anaesthesia Breathing Systems" in it.

Where am I going wrong?

Here's my jquery:

```
$('.primary-menu-1 li:nth-child(2) > a').removeAttr('href');
```

Here's the menu's html (it's generated by Wordpress):

```
<ul class="primary-menu-1">
  <li>
    <a href="https://company-test.local/" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Home</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://company-test.local/products" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Products</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-8486" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-categories">
        <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/airway-management/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
          <span class="menu-image-title">Airway Management</span>
        </a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/breathing-filters/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
          <span class="menu-image-title">Anaesthesia Breathing Systems</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/breathing-filters/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
          <span class="menu-image-title">Anaesthesia Components</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/breathing-filters/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
          <span class="menu-image-title">Breathing Filters</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/oxygen-aerosol-therapy/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
          <span class="menu-image-title">Oxygen &amp; Aerosol Therapy</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/ventilator-breathing-systems/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
          <span class="menu-image-title">Ventilator Breathing Systems</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/resuscitation/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
          <span class="menu-image-title">Resuscitation</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/suction/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
          <span class="menu-image-title">Suction</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://mycompany.com" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
          <span class="menu-image-title">Urology</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="product-up"><a href="#" class=""></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your selection from:

```
$('.primary-menu-1 li:nth-child(2) > a')
```

to:

```
$('.primary-menu-1 > li:nth-child(2) > a')
```

> [Child Selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/): (“parent > child”)

Select all the **a** elements having the **href** attribute belonging to the child ul/li. Hence you can get the second one:

```js
$('.primary-menu-1 > li:nth-child(2) > a').addClass('red');
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="primary-menu-1">
    <li>
        <a href="https://company-test.local/" class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="menu-image-title-after"><span class="menu-image-title">Products</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li id="menu-item-8486" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-categories">
                <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/airway-management/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
                    <span class="menu-image-title">Airway Management</span>
                </a></li>
            <li>
                <a class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
                    <span class="menu-image-title">Anaesthesia Breathing Systems</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
                    <span class="menu-image-title">Anaesthesia Components</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/breathing-filters/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
                    <span class="menu-image-title">Breathing Filters</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/oxygen-aerosol-therapy/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
                    <span class="menu-image-title">Oxygen &amp; Aerosol Therapy</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/ventilator-breathing-systems/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
                    <span class="menu-image-title">Ventilator Breathing Systems</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/resuscitation/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
                    <span class="menu-image-title">Resuscitation</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://company-test.local/categories/suction/" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
                    <span class="menu-image-title">Suction</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://mycompany.com" class="menu-image-title-below menu-image-not-hovered">
                    <span class="menu-image-title">Urology</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="product-up"><a href="#" class=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It doesn't remove the href from products first of all.

Comment: Sorry my mistake when writing out the question, I've updated it. I want to remove the href from products but not any of the child elements. With the jquery used it removes the href's from products and Anaesthesia Components.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.primary-menu-1 > li:nth-child(2) > a').removeAttr('href');
```